# x_train and y_train in LSTM explanation

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

If for example I have this data frame with 2 column :

```
Dates          code     count
2022-01-01     123       202
2022-01-02     123       132 
2022-01-03     123       422 
2022-01-04     123       220 
2022-01-05     123       102
```

Let say I have 80 rows, so arounf 3 month data. And, I want to use LSTM to make time series analysis.So, I type this code, splitting and scalling :

```
train_size = int(len(frame) * 0.8)
val_size = len(frame) - train_size
train, val = frame[0:train_size], frame[train_size:len(frame)]
```

scalling

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
train = scaler.fit_transform(train)
```

But it turns error that :

```
The DType <class 'numpy.dtype[int64]'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'>. This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. The full list of DTypes is: (<class 'numpy.dtype[int64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[int64]'>)
```

What exactly that error means ? thanks

Comment: Show the full error.  Also show `train.dtypes`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that your datetime format of variables in the first column is date separated by "-", and this library requires you to have numeric data type of form int64 or integers of bitesize 64 to work with. So to deal with this, I would  suggest you use pandas and break the dates into their respective day, month and year. For instance, your year is `2022` and month is `01` so it will not yield much information, hence you can use `df['Dates_days']=df[‘Dates’].dt.week` to store day of the week, which is `1,2,3,4,etc.`, information in a separate column and use it for further computation as a representative of the date.

If you have data of 3 months as you point out but of same year, you can concatenate the two columns in a way that datetime `03-04-2022` is of the form `0304` which is now `int64` or a numeric data type. You can put respective constraints on the digits and use them for whatever purpose you want to!